# Special chars with json_encode()

Tags: php, json

I'm trying the following code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$val = array('code' => 1, 'message' => 'Não encontrado!');
$res = json_encode( $val );
echo $res;
```

The answer is:

```
{ "code" : 1, "message" : "N\u00e3o encontrado!" }
```

I searched, but I couldn't find an aswer to this problem. I think it's an UTF-8 encode issue. My source file is encoded with UTF-8. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That’s not a problem. [`\u00e3` represents ã in JSON.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5)

```
js> 'ã'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
"e3"
```

If you really need it, though, [you can tell PHP not to escape it](https://php.net/json_encode):

```
$res = json_encode($val, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

[Hooray!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WWW8df)